# Cant bind a property as enum to combobox in wpf mvvm

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox, enums

I have the following scenario:

Problem : Cant bind a property as enum to combox in wpf mvvm ?

How can I bind this enum to a combobox?

1.I have an enum.

```
public enum RankType
{
   StringValue1,
   StringValue2,
   StringValue3
}
```

2.I Have a property as enum in myclass :

```
[DefaultValue(RankType.StringValue1)]
[ConvertUsing(typeof(EnumTypeConverter<RankType>))]
public RankType Rank { set; get; }
```

ConvertUsing Class,It does the conversion for me:

```
[System.AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property | AttributeTargets.Field, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class ConvertUsingAttribute:Attribute
{
    private TypeConverter _converter = null;
    public TypeConverter Converter
    {
        get
        {
            if (_converter == null)
                _converter = (TypeConverter)System.Activator.CreateInstance(TypeOfConverter);
            return _converter;
        }
    }
    public Type TypeOfConverter
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    public ConvertUsingAttribute(Type converterType)
    {
        this.TypeOfConverter = converterType;
    }
}
```

EnumTypeConverter Class:

```
public class EnumTypeConverter<T>:TypeConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type sourceType)
    {
        return sourceType == typeof(string);
    }
    public override bool CanConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, Type destinationType)
    {
        return destinationType == typeof(string);
    }
    public override object ConvertFrom(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value)
    {
        if (value != null && value is string)
        {
            return Enum.Parse(typeof(T), (string)value);// int.Parse(((string)value).Trim());
        }
        return base.ConvertFrom(context, culture, value);
    }
    public override object ConvertTo(ITypeDescriptorContext context, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture, object value, Type destinationType)
    {
        if (value != null && destinationType == typeof(string))
        {
            return ((T)value).ToString();
        }
        return base.ConvertTo(context, culture, value, destinationType);
    }
}
```

4.In ViewModel

```
private MilitaryRankType _selectedRankType;

public RankType SelectedRankType 
{  
        get { return _selectedRankType; }
        set
        {
            _selectedRankType = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(RankTypes));
        } 
}

private RankType[] _rankTypes;
public RankType[] RankTypes
{
    get
    {
       return _rankTypes ??
              (_rankTypes =Enum.GetValues(typeof(RankType)).Cast<RankType>().ToArray());
    }
}
```

5.In View

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RankTypes, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRankType}" />
```

6.I used the listview in xaml

```
   <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding EmployeesList}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3">
                        <ListView.View>
                            <GridView>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=NationalId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=CardId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            **<ComboBox SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRankType}" />**
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=FirstName, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>
                                <GridViewColumn Width="150" Header="">
                                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                        <DataTemplate>
                                            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=LastName,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,NotifyOnValidationError=True,ValidatesOnDataErrors=True,ValidatesOnExceptions=True}"/>
                                        </DataTemplate>
                                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                                </GridViewColumn>

                            </GridView>
                        </ListView.View>
                    </ListView>
```

Comment: And why you didn't implements INotifyPropertyChanged, at least?

Comment: The `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` on `ItemsSource` doesn't make any sense. The TwoWay property needs to be the `SelectedItem`. What do you expect from annotating on the `public RankType Rank { set; get; }` property that doesn't seem to be directly involved in the whole combobox bindings?

Comment: Please add more details about expected and actual behavior. Even without any TypeConverter stuff this should work without problems and I just can't reproduce whatever issue you have.

Comment: implements INotifyPropertyChanged In BaseEntity Class

Comment: My purpose Binding Enum To Combobox. Used annotating for convert enum to combobox data in view

Comment: Yes , ItemsSource  doesn't make any sense.

Comment: when i am changing the value of combobox the debugger is not goingto the set block of the selectedItem property

Comment: implements INotifyPropertyChanged In BaseEntity Class,I think it's not a problem. 
`public abstract class BaseEntity : DataErrorInfoBase, INotifyPropertyChanged { }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, I don't really know what went wrong in your code, but I can give you a working example without any fancy converter stuff:

Suppose you have the following window-content:

```
<Grid x:Name="grid1">
    <ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding SelectableRanks}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRank}"/>
</Grid>
```

And you initialize the datacontext in the window constructor:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    grid1.DataContext = new RankSelectionVM();
}
```

And this is your viewmodel:

```
public class RankSelectionVM
{
    private RankType _SelectedRank;
    public RankType SelectedRank
    {
        get { return _SelectedRank; }
        set { _SelectedRank = value; }
    }

    private RankType[] _rankTypes;
    public RankType[] SelectableRanks
    {
        get
        {
            return _rankTypes ??
                   (_rankTypes = Enum.GetValues(typeof(RankType)).Cast<RankType>().ToArray());
        }
    }
}

public enum RankType
{
    StringValue1,
    StringValue2,
    StringValue3
}
```

It doesn't have any `INotifyPropertyChanged` or any converters attached, but place a breakpoint in the `SelectedRank` setter - it should break when you select a value. If this code works for you, you have to find what you did differently to get a not-working code in your project. Otherwise you may have some very strange issue that needs special care.

Comment: When ComboBox is inside ListView not works,But when Combobox is out of the ListView works ,How to use the ancestor? For my ViewModel?

Comment: @4mir there is no `ListView` in your question, update your question if you have such issues. Also, look at the output window of visual studio, it should display some binding errors if your bindings are wrong.

Comment: @4mir now you don't have any enum `ItemsSource` at all, there is no information about the viewmodel that contains `EmployeesList`, the types in (4.) don't match one another and there are a whole bunch of other property bindings that remain a mystery to the reader of your question. Please try to give your information in a consistent way, as it is now, it's just confusing.

Comment: For ItemSource tested But Not Works!

Comment: Solution : `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor,AncestorType=ListView},Path=DataContext.RankTypes}" SelectedItem="{Binding Rank}" />`